# Inheriting an interface with a List<Interface> as a property problems

Tags: c#, .net, list, interface

I have two interfaces, one that contains a list of the other, and I want to have a class that implements the first interface but has a list of another class that implements the second interface instead of just a list of the interface.  Example:

```
namespace TestInheritance
{
    public interface IBookShelf
    {
        long Stuff { get; set; }
        List<IBook> Books { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IBook
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class BookShelf : IBookShelf
    {
        public long Stuff { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
    public class Book : IBook
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Obviously it doesn't like this.  Is there a correct way to do what I'm trying to do, or do I just have to make `BookShelf` have a `List<IBook>` and cast each `IBook` to a `Book` when I want to use it?  Looking for a pattern that could help me out here.  Thanks.

Comment: Fyi You implement an interface, not inherit it.

Comment: …unless you are another interface

Comment: @Jay Well, you've got me there.

Comment: @asawyer good call.  I got it right in the question though!

Answer (score 4):

You can make `IBookShelf` generic where you constrain the generic argument to `IBook`

Then you can have:

```
public interface IBookShelf<T> where T : IBook
{
    long Stuff { get; set; }
    List<T> Books { get; set; }
}

public class BookShelf : IBookShelf<Book>
{
    public long Stuff { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is spot on (and the first answer to show this solution).

Comment: @Jay yes and it's so close to what I'm looking for.  What I really need is to be able to reference the IBookShelf's Books list as a List<IBook> in one place, and as a List<Book> in another.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Biojayc I think if you need `List<IBook>` and `List<Book>` you have to cast either with your solution or with my solution in one of the cases. Can you add some usage examples to your question to make your question more clearer?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what you *are* trying to do - and I *suspect* it's not even clear to you. Why do you particularly want `BookShelf.Books` to be a `List<Book>`? Why is it *restricting* itself to only include `Book` values rather than `IBook` values? I suggest you consider what you'd want to happen in this situation:

```
public class EvilBook : IBook
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

IBookShelf bookShelf = new BookShelf() { Books = new List<Book>() };
bookShelf.Books.Add(new EvilBook());
```

Nothing in that code is suspicious<sup>1</sup>, with the interfaces you've given - but it ends up adding an `EvilBook` into a `List<Book>`, which surely isn't right. I often find that if the compiler's stopping me from doing something, it's useful to think about what problems I might run into if it had let me go ahead with my bad idea.

You might want to *consider* making `IBookShelf` generic:

```
public interface IBookShelf<T> where T : IBook
{
    long Stuff { get; set; }
    List<T> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public class BookShelf : IBookShelf<Book>
```

... but it really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

You might also want to ask yourself whether you really need the `IBook` interface in the first place... and also whether you really want a public *writable* property for `Books`.

---

<sup>1</sup> In terms the compiler would recognize, anyway :)

Comment: "Nothing in that code is suspicious" I personally consider any class name prefixed with "Evil" suspicious.  I guess I'm oversensitive though.

Comment: @Servy: Footnote duly added :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
namespace TestInheritance
{
    public interface IBookShelf <TBook> where TBook : IBook
    {
        long Stuff { get; set; }
        List<TBook> Books { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IBook
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class BookShelf : IBookShelf<Book>
    {
        public long Stuff { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
    public class Book : IBook
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so close to the solution I want.  What I need is for me to in one place be able to only use the IBookShelf and IBook interfaces to reference the collection, but in another use BookShelf and Book.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

1. Generally speaking casting is suspicious and best avoided. It's a great signal that something isn't right.
2. To fix the code you need to change

   ```
   public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
   ```

   to

   ```
   public List<IBook> Books { get; set; }
   ```
3. You can and should generalise things more. What kind of book shelf doesn't allow other items on it? I'm yet to see one. Consider this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
public interface IShelf
{
    long Stuff { get; }
    List<IShelfItem> Items { get; }
}
public interface IShelfItem
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Thought {get; set;}//What do I think about it?
}
public class Shelf : IShelf
{
    public Shelf(long stuff, string color) 
    {
        Stuff = stuff;
        Items = new List<IShelfItem>();
        Color = color;
    }

    public long Stuff { get; private set; }
    public List<IShelfItem> Items { get; private set; }//Note, you can still add to the list.
    public string Color { get; set; }

}
public class Book : IShelfItem
{
    public Book( string name, string thought ) {
        Name = name;
        Thought = thought;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }//Books that are on shelves don't really change their name;
    public string Thought { get; set; }

    public string BookSpecificProperty { get; set; }
}


public static void Main()
{
    Shelf myShelf = new Shelf(42, "Dull boring grey");

    myShelf.Color = "Red";


    IShelf myIShelf = myShelf;
    //myIShelf.Color = "Red"; - 'IShelf' does not contain a definition for 'Color'

    myShelf.Items.Add( new Book("Title 1", "Such a great book" ) );

    //Eos pass

    var book = myShelf.Items.SingleOrDefault( i => i.Name == "Title 1" );
    if( book != null ) {
        book.Thought = "I used to think it was such a great book. It's just OK";
        //book.BookSpecificProperty = "X"; - 'IShelfItem' does not contain a definition for 'BookSpecificProperty'
    }
}
```